# Update in ionic-angular components source code doesn't reflect in production build

Tags: android, angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have a problem with ionic toaster, so I needed to edit in its source code.
I searched that i should update in `myAppDir/node_modules/ionic-angular/components/toast`.

I updated the target file everything works fine when running `ionic serve` OR `ionic cordova build android`, But when I run `ionic cordova build android --pord`
the changes I have made is gone.

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/toast/ Install this plugin, add your own name to the plugin name and call it via the function I will try to update the plugin and npm

Comment: this is not the answer, it is not even related to the question, But thank you